# Python decorator; TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python

I have created a decorator that poses as a connection to a Sqlite database. Upon the attempt of testing the function that is being decorated `Event.create()`, I'm getting the following error: **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable**. Not sure as to what is causing this error. If it has to do with the **@classmethod** decorator, I'm not sure as to why that might be? I don't have much experience with decorators so I'm looking to understand why?

**main.py**

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect("main_db.db")

def db_connect(func):
    global db
    def wrapper_db_connect(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            with db:
                return func()
        except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
            pass
        finally:
            db.close()



class Event:

    @db_connect
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        db.execute("""
            INSERT INTO event VALUES(:name, :occurs: :desc)
        """, kwargs)

    @db_connect
    @classmethod
    def delete(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

**tests.py**

```
import unittest
import sqlite3

from main import Event


class TableSetup(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
        with self.db:
            self.db.execute("""
                CREATE TABLE event (
                    name TEXT UNIQUE,
                    occurs TEXT,
                    description TEXT
                )
                """)

    def tearDown(self):
        print("DROP")
        with self.db:
            self.db.execute("DROP TABLE event")


class TestEventOrganizer(TableSetup):

    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        self.event_user_data = {
            'name': 'Event A',
            'occurs': '2020-3-1',
            'desc': 'Event A'
        }

    def test_create_event(self):

        Event.create(**self.event_user_data)

        self.assertEqual(db.total_changes, 1)
        self.assertEqual(str(self.stored_event), "Event A")

    def tearDown(self):
        super().tearDown()
```

Comment: Your decorator does not return `wrapper_db_connect`.

Comment: I'm voting to close the question since it seems to be just a typo. If you still don't understand, please simplify the problem into an [mre] so that it's easier to write an answer.